# Regex to match a string with spaces until the first "="

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string that looks something like:

```
abC d eFg=hiJk lmNop
```

...and i want to match all characters from the beginning up to `"="`:

```
abC d eFg
```

I have tried to accomplish this with:

```cs
string str = "abC d eFg=hiJk lmNop";
Regex.Match(str, @"^.*?(?==)").ToString()
```

However, this regex returns only the last word which is `"eFg"`.

Comment: Why don't you just split at `=`?

Comment: Overkill... simply use *mystring.Split('=').First();*

Comment: Thanks, but I needed regex

Comment: Why do you particularly need a regular expression for this?

Comment: Because I'm parsing files with long and complicated text and I noticed I had a small problem with spaces

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the pattern:

```
^[^=]*
```

You can also split by `"="` and take the first splitted value.

Comment: If you prefix that pattern with another `^` then you don't have to "take the first match" - it will only match with the start of the string.

Comment: Short and sweet with two options for Yona, nice. :) +1

Answer (score 6):

A fairly easy practice would be to use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), which is non-regex.

```
string test = "abC d eFg=hiJk lmNop";
string current = test.Split('=')[0];
```

This returns an array of strings split at the `=`.

- Index 0 is `abC d eFg`
- Index 1 is `hiJk lmNop`

Using LINQ you can also use `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first value, which may be a little bit more readable, as opposed to the `[0]` index after the split.

```cs
string current = test.Split('=').FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` would be better than `First` in the event of no matches